# Include files on nested references

Tags: .net

I have a library project A that uses some SQL scripts, thus those scripts are defined as content.  This works fine if the executing project references directly this library project: the scripts are copied in the output compilation directory of the calling project.
But if add a reference from project B to project A, and then a reference from the executing project to project B the scripts are copied in the bin of the project B but not on the executing project, where I need them.
How I can manage to pass the files from the project A to the executing project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Project A relies on those scripts but the other projects don't (directly, only through their use of A), it shouldn't really be necessary for the other projects to "know" about them.

One solution would be to set them as an [embedded resource](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) in Project A and have it read them out of it's own assembly rather than off the filesystem.